# How to create a new application with `ng new`?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am using node v10.16.0 but every time I try to run "ng new" or "ng -v" I get an error saying I am running V6.11.3 and that I should use version 10.9 or greater.

I have tried to clean the cache using "npm cache clean". I have tried to uninstall and reinstall angular and node. I have check the system variables and add the path.

```
C:\Users\Yv-Arnel\code>node -v
v10.16.0

C:\Users\Yv-Arnel\code>ng -v
You are running version v6.11.3 of Node.js, which is not supported by Angular CLI 8.0+.
The official Node.js version that is supported is 10.9 or greater.

Please visit https://nodejs.org/en/ to find instructions on how to update Node.js.
```

Comment: Was the CLI installed when you had an earlier version of Node? Have you tried to `npm install -g @angular/cli` again?

Comment: How is this possible `node -v
v10.16.0 
` but the error says `You are running version v6.11.3 of Node.js` do you have 2 node.js installed ?

Comment: You're on Windows. Go to your control panel and uninstall NodeJS. Remove it from your PATH environment variables and then go to their website and install the LTS version.

Comment: You need node.js v12 (not the LTS) to run angular v8 (latest)

Answer (score 0):

**There was a node version installed using Laragon**

I was using Laragon a year ago and I installed node.js using Laragon.
I uninstall node with Control Panel But I was still able to run "node -v" because there was two versions installed.So I looked for the directory where Laragon installed it and delete it after that I installed the latest versions of node aivalaible on their website and I was able to run "ng new".